# error increasing with no of estimators in adaboost

Tags: machine-learning, svm, python

My error gets increased when i increase the n_estimators value in

```
ada=AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=1, base_estimator=SVC(probability=True,kernel="rbf",gamma=.1,C=1))
```

for n_estmators the predictor is giving the least error, whereas as i increase the value of n_estmator then the error also increases

what could be interpreted from this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

AdaBoost needs internally a weak classifier to work, not SVMs. Usually it is something like a threshold on a single feature. If you use a strong classifier then you end-up with an overfitted model.